# HTML forms and argparse

Tags: python, html, argparse

I currently use argparse for writing command line driven scripts in python. I'm considering making a server which provides a front-end for many of these scripts (some computers may not have the RAM, processing speed, etc. to run them locally). So I'm wondering about different ways to hook into these scripts via a webpage.

The goal would to have the equivalent of a webpage generated off the argparse content (for instance, the arguments with choices would display as a combo-box, arguments that are boolean would be a checkbox, etc.). Since argparse is fairly well defined, I imagine it might be possible to create a wrapper around argparse functions to generate the needed HTML.

Any suggestions for how to do this painlessly?

Edit: Here's an example of what I am envisioning.

Here is a simple script using argparse and below it some html which I am envisioning being translated from argparse.

```
import argparse, sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', '--file', nargs='?', help="The fasta file to process.", type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=sys.stdin)
parser.add_argument('-o', '--out', nargs='?', help="The file to write processed file to.", type=argparse.FileType('w'), default=sys.stdout)
parser.add_argument('--something', help="This does something", choices=['a','b'], type=str, default='a')
parser.add_argument('--somethingelse', help="This does something else", action='store_true', type=bool)

def main():
    args = parser.parse_args()
    #do stuff here such a reading in files, processing, and delivering output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

With html this is like this (I'm terrible at HTML, so it's probably wrong/a hack)

```
<form>
File: <input type="text" name="file"><br>
Out: <input type="text" name="out"><br>
<select name="something">
<option value="a" selected>a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
</select><br>
Somethingelse: <input type="checkbox" name="somethingelse" value="true"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Where then hitting submit would cause the server to execute the script with those parameters. In essence, I want my server to then send the command as if I typed it in, if we're working with an output file it would give the user something downloadable (but that's a problem for another time)

Comment: Can I suggest you look into [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I haven't played much with Django -- but the process would be: write code in Django to produce the form and then write a script that accepts what Django sends. If I update the script, I need to update the form. I think if the form was generated from the script I would only ever have to change the script and the form would automagically stay up to date. I would like that approach since it's only 1 step and 1 file to maintain :)

Comment: That's not exactly how it works. You do not need to maintain two files. You generate the form with a Django view and some templated HTML, but the same view can also handle form submissions. Check out [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view). You are essentially talking about having a Python file generate a webpage, which is exactly what Django does.

Comment: Ah, but that would be good if I was only operating as a webpage. I also have users who just use the command line tools - so there are 2 needs I am trying to address. This is an exploration in expanding the user base by providing a browser-based front end (for users who are command line illiterate or need a faster cpu where things can be centralized on)

Comment: However, that link you provided made me believe I could write something to create Django forms (such as the ContactForm class) through wrapping some argparser methods.

Comment: You probably already know that you can use `argparse` without using `sys.argv`. The form submission data may be passed in as well to the same script, if you like.

Comment: Sounds like you want to generate an `HTML` `form` that is modeled on an `argparse` `parser`.  I can imagine using the `add_argument` parameters to produce input field specifications.  I'd suggest doing some manual translations, and then for looking patterns that would help you automate the task.  Post some of those translations to further the discussion.

Comment: I've added some `WSGI` notes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this roughly what you want to do?

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='sample parser')
arg1 = parser.add_argument('--foo')
print parser
print arg1

html = """
<form name="%(prog)s action="%(action)s" method="get">
%(description)s
<input type="text" name="%(dest)s"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
"""
d = vars(parser)
d.update(vars(arg1))
d['action'] = 'html_form.xxx'
print html%d
```

which displays:

```
ArgumentParser(prog='stack21586315.py', usage=None, description='sample parser',
    version=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>,
    conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)

_StoreAction(option_strings=['--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None,
    default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)

<form name="stack21586315.py action="html_form.xxx" method="get">
sample parser
<input type="text" name="foo"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I'm generating a dictionary from the attributes of the `parser` and its `action`, and using those to fill in slots in the `form` string.

---

A basic WSGI function involves sending a `response` via `start_response`, and receiving a `request` (here in the `envirion` argument).  Details with vary with the framework.

The url of this module (and function) is specified in the form's `action` attribute.  How the values are sent depends on the `method` (get/post).  The values are found in `environ['QUERY_STRING']`.  There are various tools for parsing this string, either in the `cgi` or `urlparse` modules (or see your framework).  The parsed request should end up looking much like `vars(args)`.

```
def my_send_app(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK' # HTTP Status
    headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain')] # HTTP Headers
    start_response(status, headers)

    # The returned object is going to be printed
    # create the HTML including the form; return as list of strings
    return [...]

def my_receive_app(envirion, start_responce):
    # Returns a dictionary containing lists as values.
    d = urlparse.parse_qs(environ['QUERY_STRING'])
    # d should be similar to vars(args)
    # apply the values in d
    # use start_responce to reply to the browser
```

http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_request_parsing_get

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is enough for me to scrape together a solution.